# indexOf() doesn't find the value in array

Tags: arrays, timestamp, indexof

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239260/google-apps-script-workflow-approval-selecting-approval-broken), I'm working on a proof of concept to capture an item request via Google form, email it for approval and the approval result posted back to the corresponding row in Google sheet. The row is searched from an array, using the timestamp as key.

I faced 2 challenges: First, the timestamp in the array is in a different format and sometimes differed by 1 second. I tweaked this by adjusting the format to match how the array values look like and run a 2nd search if the first timestamp search fails. I hope this is foolproof but let me know if there is a better way. I couldn't figure out why there is a 1-second difference sometimes.

I got stuck on the **second challenge: I'm unable to search successfully the timestamp in the array** at all. indexOf() always returns a value of -1.

Will appreciate any help. 
Please be detailed if needed, I'm a newbie.

Here's my code:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  // Response columns: Timestamp    Requester Email Item    Cost
  var email = e.namedValues["Requester Email"];
  var item = e.namedValues["Item"];
  var cost = e.namedValues["Cost"];
  var timestamp = e.namedValues["Timestamp"];

  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

  // Enhancement: include timestamp to coordinate response  
  var options = '?approval=%APPROVE%&timestamp=%TIMESTAMP%&reply=%EMAIL%'
         .replace("%TIMESTAMP%",encodeURIComponent(e.namedValues["Timestamp"]))
         .replace("%EMAIL%",e.namedValues["Requester Email"])         
  var approve = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Approved"); 
  var reject = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Rejected");

  var html = "<body>"+
                "<h2>Please review</h2><br />"+
                "Request from: " + email + "<br />"+
                "For: "+item +", at a cost of: $" + cost + "<br /><br />"+ 
                "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
                "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
             "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Approval Request", 
                    "Requires html",
                    {htmlBody: html});  
}


function doGet(e) {

  var answer = (e.parameter.approval === 'Approved') ? 'Buy it!' : 'Not this time, Keep saving'; 
  var timestamp = e.parameter.timestamp;
  var newtimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestamp), "GMT+8", "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0800 (SGT)'");  //reformat timestamp to match the ones in the data array
  var approvalCol = 5;

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Purchase Request", 
                    "Your manager said: "+ answer);   

  // Update approval status back to the sheet
  var wsID = "<myworksheetID>";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsID).getSheetByName("Requests");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var oneColArray = new Array();
  for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
     oneColArray.push(data[i][0]); // taking index 0 means I'll get column A of each row and put it in the new array
  }

  var row = oneColArray.indexOf(newtimestamp);

  Logger.log("\ntimestamp: " + timestamp + "\n\n" + "newtimestamp: " + newtimestamp + "\n\n" + "oneColArray: \n" + oneColArray);

  if (row < 0) {                                     //not found
    //Lower timestamp by 1 second. Sometimes there is a 1-second difference than the one in the array. I don't know why
    var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestamp), "GMT+8",'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var revisedtimestamp = new Date((date.getTime() - (1/(24*60*60)*1000)));

    // now search again using the adjusted timestamp
    var row = oneColArray.indexOf(revisedtimestamp); 

    if (row < 0) {
       Logger.log("\ntimestamp: " + timestamp + "\n\n" + "newtimestamp: " + newtimestamp + "\n\n" + "oneColArray: \n" + oneColArray + "\n\n" + "revisedtimestamp: " + revisedtimestamp);
       throw new Error ("Request not found in list.");
    } else {
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, approvalCol).setValue(e.parameter.approval);
    }
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, approvalCol).setValue(e.parameter.approval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this [post](http://How%20to%20get%20%60indexOf()%60%20cells%20value%20or%20convert%20an%20object%20to%20a%20String?).

I changed this line:

```
var row = oneColArray.indexOf(newtimestamp);
```

to this to convert the array into string, and indexOf() returns the starting point where it finds the first occurrence of the timestamp. From the return value I just calculated what row it is in the worksheet:

```
var row = oneColArray.join().indexOf(newtimestamp);
```

Another variation which I preferred more is looping through the data array's timestamp column, in each loop the value is converted into string before doing indexOf(). I just need to add 1 to [i] to get the actual row in the worksheet.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       var row = data[i][0].toString().indexOf(newtimestamp);
    if (row > -1) {
      var a = i;
      break;
    }
  }
```